# [Emu 8086]Can't open file

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

The program should open the file,read from it and print the first 4 characters.

- I can't figure out what the problem is.I even created the file myself there and it still cannot open the file.

  ```
  org 100h
  jmp start  
  filename db "C:\f1.txt",0
  errormessage: db "Ndodhi nje gabim gjate ekzekutimit$"  
  Buffer db 50h dup(?)
  start:   
    lea dx,filename
    mov ah,3Dh
    mov al,0
    int 21h
    jc error  
    mov bx,ax         
    mov ah,3Fh
    mov cx,4
    lea dx,Buffer
    int 21h
    jmp end
  error:mov dx,offset errormessage
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
  end: ret
  ```

Comment: Have you *carefully* read the documentation for ah=3dh function of int 21h? Hint: what goes in al?

Comment: I saw the documentation,seems like al needs the acess mode.I added mov al,0 and it still does not work.Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Examine the error code returned in ax!

Comment: Move `ax` to `bx` (file handle) BEFORE moving 3Fh to `ah`!

Comment: @FrankKotler yeah, I missed that one. However even if the read fails no error message will be output. Also the file is never closed (ah=3eh if memory serves). Not strictly necessary here, but just for sake of good form.

Comment: @FrankKotler still doesn't work bro

Comment: @AntonTykhyy I will complete the program once I solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an emulator. Your program has access to an emulated `C:` drive, which is not the real `C:` drive of your PC.

As it says on http://www.emu8086.com/ :

> dos file system is emulated in \vdrive\ folder

In other words, put file `f1.txt` in folder `c:\emu8086\vdrive\c`; your program will see the file in what *appears* to be `C:\`.

If you installed emu8086 in a folder other than `c:\emu8086`, then obviously you will have to look for `vdrive` there.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your data (all the `db` stuff) underneath a `.data` directive, and the code under `.code`. In an old-fashioned `.com` file, it does not matter, but in an `.exe`, the data segment (`ds`) and the code segment (`cs`) are different, and you are supposed to tell the assembler what belongs where.

Explanation: the DOS function expects the filename to be on address `ds:dx`, but chances are, there is nothing there (likely just NUL characters, which is interpreted as an empty string) because the filename is on address `cs:dx`.

Comment: I tried and did what you said and it still says it can't open the file

Answer (score 0):

If the error message prints correctly you can be sure that the DS segment register is set correctly and the problem must be before the first "int 21h".

You should open the file with a hexadecimal editor and check if the string "c:\f1.txt" is really present. Some assemblers handle backslashes in strings like C so you'll have to write two backslashes ("c:\\f1.txt") to get one backslash in the .COM file.